# Animate on scroll function mess up on using touch countrols of mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Animation on scroll function is working fine on desktop view but it mess up the scrolling and scroll to random sections when I switch to mobile view and uses touch to scroll the screen. This is my animate on scroll function :

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    $('.skillbar').each(function(i){  
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(this).offset().top ){ 
    jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
            width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
        },6000);       
  }   
}); 

});
```

If I use the windows on scroll function, it mess up the mobile view. Please help to solve this issue so that animate on scroll can work on both mobile view with touch scroll and desktop view without messing the scroll.

For more Information these are the other scroll events:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 54)
        }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '#mainNav',
        offset: 80
    });

    // Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
    $('#navbarResponsive>ul>li>a').click(function() {
        $('#navbarResponsive').collapse('hide');
    });

    // jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
            $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
        } else {
            $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
        }
    });

    })(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

Comment: So both functions are working separately but not toguether ? Is that it?

Comment: Touchmove is working fine with mobile view, but touchmove doesn't work with desktop scrolling and If I use window scroll function, It mess up the mobile view scroll, so is there any function that works on both mobile and desktop view. Thanks

Comment: Yes both are working separately but not together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Since this is the same function for both events...
Maybe calling it on the same handler and use an `or` to trigger only once will do the trick.

```
$(window).on("touchmove scroll", function(e) { 

    // Do the function on ONLY ONE of the two event.
    if(e.type=="touchmove" || e.type=="scroll"){
        $('.skillbar').each(function(i){  
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(this).offset().top ){
                jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').not(".triggered").addClass("triggered").animate({
                    width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
                },6000);       
            } 
        }); 
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

I've added a subtility using a `triggered` class.

```
.not(".triggered").addClass("triggered")
```

One the first iteration of the `.each()` function, none of the `skillbar-bar` has the `trigered` class.
So let's add it! Then trigger the animation.

On the second and all next iterations, the `triggered` class removes all `skillbar-bar` which already have the `triggered` class out of the collection.

This prevent the `animate()` function to be fired more than once on each `skillbar-bar`.

I think this was the issue.
Let me know if it works !

Comment: Still the same problem, this function is not unbinding the scroll handler.

Comment: Oups... I forgot the `e` in `$("body").on("touchmove scroll", function(e) { `, sorry.

Comment: I've found it. Juste replace `$("body").on(...` by `$(window).on(...` and clear your cache, since it is in an external .js file.

Comment: This is a real beautifull animation ;)

Comment: Still same problem, animation is working fine, but when you scroll to the footer of the website in google chrome mobile view, it automatically scrolls to education section.

Comment: You placed it at the very end of agency.js. Try placing it within `$(document).ready(function() {`... AND this is still `$("body")`... Replace it by `$(window)`

Comment: Now I don't have access to my computer. I will try this tomorrow and let you know. ☺ Thanks

Comment: Ok ;) Check my profile if you want to contact me outside SO. ;)

Comment: Good Morning Louys.. I have tried placing it within $(document).ready(function()... it is still not working.. Today I closely inspected the mobile view.. using touchmove the scrolling is still messy but not as messy as window on scroll function.. I don't know why only this animation is messing my website.. I have also used winow on scroll function at other places on my website, they are working fine.. but only this animation is messing the scrolling.. If I place the animation out of scroll function it works fine , but when I place this animation in scroll function, it mess up the scrolling

Comment: Hi! I've edited my answer with something I did put aside yesterday when you told me that the functions were running correctly separatly... But, based on your last comment, "multiple `animate()` on same element" finally looks like to be the real issue. Have a look and tell me! ;)

Comment: It's working now. Thanks for helping me out with this scroll function I owe you big time. Cheers :)

Comment: It was a pleasure... Your page layout is one of the most beautyfull I've seen. I need to do one for myself... So I'm bookmarking it for inspiration. ;) Cheers! (Consider an upvote too ;) )

Comment: Thanks.. It's not 100% ready yet. I will finish it by the end of this week and then i will send you the updated website link for review. ;) Thanks again and have a good day.